Angular - how to hide a div when I select a language with ngx translate from another component
I have and angular app. it is angular 16. Im using ngx tranlate for languages. What I need is this:
In my header-component I have have the dropdown to select the language: English or Spanish.
In my home-component I have div-A and div-B.
header-component
The ngx translate select for languages - html
           <select
              class="select select-bn"
              #langSelect
              (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)"
            >
              <option
                *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()"
                [value]="lang"
                [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang"
              >
                {{ lang }}
              </option>
            </select>

header-component
ts code
  constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,

  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'es']);

    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang?.match(/en|es/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    this.model.lang = translate.currentLang;
  }

home-component
    <div class=" div-A fs-0 open-sans open-sans-titles">
      <p>
        <span class="">{{ "home.titleA" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-A gc-1 ml-n1">{{ "home.titleB" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-01">{{ "home.titleC" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-02">{{ "home.titleD" | translate }}</span>
        <span class="fs-02 text-primary">{{ "home.titleE" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="div-B fs-0 open-sans open-sans-titles">
      <p>
        <span class="">{{ "home.titleA" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-A gc-1 ml-n1">{{ "home.titleB" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-01">{{ "home.titleC" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="fs-02">{{ "home.titleD" | translate }}</span>
        <span class="fs-02 text-primary">{{ "home.titleE" | translate }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>

When I select Spanish I would like to hide div-A and show div-B and viceversa.
PD: If this already exits and it is very usual please address me to the right path and I will go and read and learn!...

For starters: both divs are the same and only the class div-A / div-B is different?

if only the class is the only different, u can just switch the class with ngClass

Hello. The divs will be different in content. Right now I havent create the new content but there are going to have different content

You can add *ngIf condition with translate.currentLang to show div's according selected current language
home-component.ts
constructor(
  public translate: TranslateService,

) {
}

home-component.html
<div class=" div-A fs-0 open-sans open-sans-titles" *ngIf="'en' === translate.currentLang">
  <p>
    <span class="">{{ "home.titleA" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-A gc-1 ml-n1">{{ "home.titleB" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-01">{{ "home.titleC" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-02">{{ "home.titleD" | translate }}</span>
    <span class="fs-02 text-primary">{{ "home.titleE" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="div-B fs-0 open-sans open-sans-titles" *ngIf="'es' === translate.currentLang">
  <p>
    <span class="">{{ "home.titleA" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-A gc-1 ml-n1">{{ "home.titleB" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-01">{{ "home.titleC" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="fs-02">{{ "home.titleD" | translate }}</span>
    <span class="fs-02 text-primary">{{ "home.titleE" | translate }}</span>
  </p>
</div>


Ok, this is what I meant.. Really simple but I could not see it. As soon I'm back I'm my pc I will try and let you know.

Thanks a lot Dakshesh Baldaniya. This is just perfect!!..but you already knew XD

@gagdmac what i know?

That your answer was right and it will work!

it it works please upvote and approve.

I have approved your answer but I can't upvote it yet! not enough reputation!

okay, thanks!, appreciate.
